# Como adicionar mais campos em registro de usuários Wordpress wp-login

Tags: html, wordpress, aplicação-web, wordpress-theme

Desenvolvi um site que contem um cadastro de usuário, depois o administrador do site libera este cadastro, porem preciso adicionar mais alguns campos e por padrão o Wordpress só pede nome de usuário e e-mail, como adiciono por exemplo nome e telefone nesta cadastro, [link para o formulário de cadastro](http://www.recantodasaguascondominio.com.br/wp-login.php?action=register)

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu costumo dizer, as vezes só é preciso um pouco de pesquisa.
Encontrei um plugin que faz exactamente o prentendido, chamado:

> [**Cimy User Extra Fields**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/)

Este plugin oferece a opção de adicionar coisas como:

```
text, textarea, textarea-rich, password, checkbox, radio, drop-down, picture, picture-url, registration-date, avatar, file, date
```

Podes ler a descrição completa das características deste plugin e ver mais *screenshots* em:

Cimy User Extra Fields - [Descrição](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/)
Cimy User Extra Fields - [Screenshots](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/screenshots/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Valeu cara ajudou bastante

Comment: De nada @ViniciusVAz , quando tiveres oportunidade, considera marcar a minha resposta como correcta carregando no `"sinal de visto"` que se encontra por baixo das setas de votação =)

Comment: O código desse plugin melhorou muito mas ainda é bastante bruto. Tem que filtrar, mas [aqui tem umas soluções boas pra fazer isso a mão](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=login+fields+is%3Aq). Vale a pena conferir outros plugins também.